# LISP binary trees - max depth

Tags: tree, lisp, common-lisp

Using this way of representing trees: (A (B) (C (D) (E)))  (which, from what I've seen I think it's the standard way, but I might be wrong).

```
  A
 / \
 B  C
   / \
   D  E
```

I want to find the maximum depth and construct a list with the nodes from the root to that level.
For the above example the answer would be 2 (the root is on level 0) with one of the following two lists: (A C D) or (A C E).

The maxdepth algorithm should be simple:

```
maxdepth( tree ):
    if ( !tree )    return 0
    leftdepth   = maxdepth( left sub-tree )
    rightdepth  = maxdepth( right sub-tree )
    return max ( leftdepth + 1, rightdepth + 1 )
```

So I tried something similar:

```
(defun maxdepth(l)
    (cond
        ((null l) 0)
        ((atom l) 0)
        ((+ 1 (max (maxdepth(car l)) (maxdepth(cdr l)))))
    )
)
```

CAR tree should give me the left sub-tree, and CDR tree should give me the right one. If I reached the end or an atom (this feels wrong) I stop. I check if maxdepth(car l) is bigger than maxdepth(cdr l) and go further with the bigger one. 
But this gives me 8 for the above tree. And I haven't started to construct the list yet.

How far from a good idea and a good implementation am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood your requirements to be that you want to return two values: the depth and one (arbitrary) path from root to full depth.  This is a good opportunity to show how you can use multiple-value semantics.

At the root, the skeleton looks like this (assuming a binary tree):

```
(defun max-depth (tree)
  (if (null (rest tree))
      (values 0 tree)
      (with-sub-depths (left-depth left-path right-depth right-path tree)
        (if (> right-depth left-depth)
            (values (1+ right-depth) (cons (car tree) right-path))
            (values (1+ left-depth) (cons (car tree) left-path))))))
```

`With-sub-depths` is a placeholder for the actual recursion for now.

Assuming that we get this to work, `max-depth` will return the desired two values.  If we just call it and use its return value, we get the first (primary) value:

```
(let ((d (max-depth tree)))
  (format t "Depth is ~a." d))
```

If we need the additional values, we can use `multiple-value-bind`:

```
(multiple-value-bind (depth path) (max-depth tree)
  (format t "Depth is ~a.  Example path: ~s." depth path))
```

We now need to use `multiple-value-bind` in the recursion, too:

```
(defun max-depth (tree)
  (if (null (rest tree))
      (values 0 tree)
      (multiple-value-bind (left-depth left-path) (max-depth (second tree))
        (multiple-value-bind (right-depth right-path) (max-depth (third tree))
          (if (> right-depth left-depth)
              (values (1+ right-depth) (cons (first tree) right-path))
              (values (1+ left-depth) (cons (first tree) left-path)))))))
```

Trying it at the REPL shows all values returned:

```
CL-USER> (max-depth '(A (B) (C (D) (E))))
2
(A C D)
```

Comment: And here I was constructing the list and then passing it to length thinking that I can't do both things at the same time. This is nice :)

Answer (score 3):

In the representation you're using, `(car l)` is the current node, `(cadr l)` is the left subtree, and `(caddr l)` is the right subtree. So your recursive step should be:

```
(+ 1 (max (maxdepth (cadr l)) (maxdepth (caddr l)))
```

You're also missing the `t` condition in the default clause of your `cond`. So the full version should be:

```
(defun maxdepth (l)
  (cond ((null l) 0)
        ((atom l) 0)
        (t (+ 1 (max (maxdepth (cadr l)) (maxdepth (caddr l)))))))

(maxdepth '(A (B) (C (D) (E))))
```

returns `3`

Comment: It was actually an obvious mistake from my part. I think I would have lost a lot of time trying to figure that out. Now, when it comes to building that list: is it a good idea to append the current node every time I choose a sub-tree?

Comment: If you're going down into a subtree, you don't need the parent node any more.